# VSCode: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I made a hello world program and it worked perfectly.But I added another class with name "Program2" with same structure but with some other output..its throwing given :

[image]

> Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to
>   specify the type that contains the entry point.

I get that it has two main method,and I haven't assigned a class to exceute at run time..but the issue is ..I am not able to find the solution...which could be as simple as

*Project => Properties => Application => Startup object => Program2*

if I were using Visual Studio ,But in Visual Code,there is launch.json and other json files...where all the settings are defined.

This definitely looks like Angular.But since I dont know that or VS code.

Any ideas?

Comment: By far the most friction-free way is to only have one eligible `Main` function in the first place. I mean, even in cases where you legitimately have multiple `Main` functions you'd like to use (like poor man's unit tests) it's a pain to have to recompile with a switch just to get the right one. Not that Code should have no way to do this, but...